# Syntax Error installing scikit-learn using pip from SHELL

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, python-import, python-install

The following gives a syntax error:

```
python -m pip install scikit-learn
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
There is a "^" under the 2nd 'p' in pip.

I am using the **SHELL**. There are two programs in the Windows 10 program group: "Python 3.6 (32-bit)" and "IDLE (Python 3.6 32bit)."  I am using the first one, which opens a small black command window.

The Python 3.6 man page says this is the way to install modules:

```
python -m pip install SomePackage
```

It also says pip is automatically included in Python 3.6.
It also says that with 3.6 all dependencies of SomePackage are automatically installed (scikit-learn has two dependencies).

I tried "import pip" in another attempt, and I got exactly the same results.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "I am using the **SHELL**." No, you're using a Python REPL. Try using a command shell instead.

Comment: Where is it???  Why is it not listed in the Windows program group after installation????????

Comment: Because it's not part of the installation, it comes with Windows itself.

Comment: Thank you.  The man page should say "Windows command prompt" rather than "The standard packaging tools are all designed to be used from the command line."

Comment: Technically the command line only exists in conjunction with the command prompt, but the documentation could be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs when you try to run `pip` from the Python interpreter. Instead, run from the Windows Command Prompt and you should have no issues.

Comment: Thank you. The man page should say "Windows command prompt" rather than "The standard packaging tools are all designed to be used from the command line."  The Python REPL looks like a command screen.

Comment: Well, it didn't auto-install the dependencies numpy and scipy.  Numpy manually installed okay.  Scipy failed to install with a long list of errors...

Comment: @MikeSmith anything in particular?

Comment: I found a special version of scipy for Windows 10 here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and now all is okay.. Thanks.